# mysql select data from two tables and different structure

Tags: php, mysql, select, structure

Hi there i'm building up a kind of agenda/website with php/mysql.
This agenda has public events and users' personal notes ordered by date.
I need to load all the events from EVENTS TABLE in database and the notes from NOTES TABLE.
But those two tables have a completely different structure and they just have one same field: DATETIME.

How can i sort by date public events and personal notes then?

Please help me out! =)
thanks luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improving Don's answer per OP comments, you can add a column to know what table the row was in.

```
SELECT  'events' As Tbl,
        datetime,
        location,
        organizer,
        NULL as notes
FROM    events
UNION
ALL
SELECT  'user_notes' As Tbl,
        datetime,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        notes
FROM    user_notes
ORDER
BY      datetime DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UNION ALL` with two queries. Each table's query will just have `NULL` in all the columns for the other table. For example:

```
SELECT  'event' as type,
        datetime,
        location,
        organizer,
        NULL as notes
FROM    events
UNION
ALL
SELECT  'user_note',
        datetime,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        notes
FROM    user_notes
ORDER
BY      datetime DESC
```

The type field can either be a string or an integer to easily distinguish which table the row came from.

Comment: thanks! but how do I know if the row im echoing out is coming from user_notes or events (cause i need to style different as well)? there's something more elegant than leave for example a NULL field as first so when $row['0']==NULL i know it belongs to a specific table?? =)

Comment: As @The Scrum Meister suggested, you can add an extra field to distinguish one table from the other. I've updated my answer.