# Select data from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, archive

I need to select data from two different tables to create a history/ archive for my website like this:

2012

- August(6)
- September(4)
- October(2)

I'm aware that there is a question similar to this in stackoverflow: [PHP MYSQL Blog Archive Menu by Year and Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053636/php-mysql-blog-archive-menu-by-year-and-month)

However, I have two similar yet different tables.

I have tried using this example: [mysql select data from two tables and different structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032995/mysql-select-data-from-two-tables-and-different-structure), but I always get the error of "#1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'"

Is there any other ways that I can combine to get my data like above?

My two tables' fields and structures are:

1) news

- id (int 5)
- title (varchar 200)
- content (text)
- date_added (datetime)

2) equipment

- id (int 5)
- title (varchar 45)
- content (varchar 250)
- date_added (date)

Note: The tables' id are their own individual id for the article. My tables haven nothing in common with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I thought the data types were the issue and you needed to cast the types to match:

```
SELECT id, title, content, cast(date_added as Date) FROM NEWS
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, title, cast(content as text), date_added FROM EQUIPMENT;
```

However when I tried it out myself I found all types converted implicitly. I took another look at your description and delved deeper into the collation issue. It's my belief that the `content` column in the `news` table is either a different character set and/or a different collation type from the `content` column in the `Equipment` table. This could be true for the title columns or the whole tables. You need to try converting. I would suggest this:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  convert(title using utf8) collate utf8_bin, 
  convert(content using utf8) collate utf8_bin, 
  date_added 
FROM 
  NEWS
UNION ALL

SELECT 
  id, 
  convert(title using utf8) collate utf8_bin, 
  convert(content using utf8) collate utf8_bin, 
  date_added 
FROM 
  EQUIPMENT;
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I've tried the codes but I get error when I tried to cast as text. From what I had read, cast or convert only allows BINARY[(N)], CHAR[(N)], DATE, DATETIME, DECIMAL[(M[,D])], SIGNED [INTEGER], TIME UNSIGNED [INTEGER]?

Comment: Try it wih just casting the date_added column. Varchar may implicity convert to text. You could also try selecting with just the date_added or the content columns to determine which column is giving the problem.

Comment: @TessLaker I've realized something new about your problem and have added to my answer above with new information.

Answer (score 2):

it's because you are trying to Union different types together which is impossible. The Columns count and type should match so that you can Union their tables.

date & datetime - do you think these really match?

OK, criticism is enought :) now the solution, I think you need something like a temp table so that you can 1.query one of your tables, 2.convert types to whatever matches your other table, 3.insert into temp table.

Now your temp table matches your table. Go and Union them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on why I can't 'union' them! The two tables were done by two different people, thus the differences.

Comment: yeah @Ilion temp table is not necessary.